# Why does exit(65280) cause Perl to exit with an exit status of 0?

Tags: perl

Why does `exit(65280)` cause Perl to exit with an exit status of 0?

```
perl -e 'exit(65280)'
echo $?   # returns 0
```

Answer (score 5):

> exit only takes integer args from 0 - 255.

Also:

> Out of range exit values
>   can result in unexpected exit codes. An exit value greater than 255
>   returns an exit code modulo 256. For example, exit 3809 gives an exit
>   code of 225 (3809 % 256 = 225).

Take a look at this page from *The Linux Documentation Project* on [*Exit Codes With Special Meanings*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).

Perl is written in C and so is Bash.  So I think its the same for Perl.  I guess Bash has this better documented than Perl?  Or else I'm not looking in the right place in the Perl docs.

Comment: Perl only says: "The only universally recognized values for EXPR are 0 for success and 1 for error; other values are subject to interpretation depending on the environment in which the Perl program is running." The documentation probably assumes you already know that Unix exit values are taken modulo 256.

Comment: `exit` can take larger than 255 on Windows.

Comment: @melpomene, That just reflects the limits of what C guarantees. The actual range of values are range values are much larger (at least 0..255) on all modern systems (except maybe on VMS with which I'm not familiar).

Comment: @Keith Thompson, I know.  I just said that. Did you misread what I said? Anyway, the point is that melopomene statement is useless since it reflects the entirety of systems C can run on, and not the ones the script will be run on